# CSS acting weird with change in reading direction

Tags: html, css

Good morning,

I have a weird reaction with some CSS, when changing the document reading direction from ltr to rtl.

When I try to display some text such as an adress:
28 Main Street - XXXX -XXX -XXXX

I end up with this
Main Street - XXXX -XXX -XXXX 28

See for yourself
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGJZOg

```
<html dir="rtl">
  <span>28 Main Street - 00000 - CITY - COUNTRY</span>
  </br>
  <span>Main Street - 00000 - CITY - COUNTRY</span>
  </br>
  <span>plop 28 Main Street - 00000 - CITY - COUNTRY</span>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's how its supposed to work. Check out these links. [Right-to-left text in HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir) and [CSS Direction](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp) . For reversing the text, check this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/reversing-text/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes but why when I use reverse on a text like "28 something - something more" I end up with "something - something more 28", while if i try to render something like "p 28 something - something more" i end up with the "p 28 something - something more". I does not really seems to follow any logic

Comment: It has something to do with the inherent direction of the characters.
https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/ and https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html

Comment: ok, did not really understood the logic behind it, but as suggested I'm going to wrap the adress and set the direction to ltr, as it is an adress. Anyway thx

Answer (score 4):

This line is why your text goes from right to left :

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

`dir="rtl"` literally means [**write this text right-to-left**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp)!

---

What (I think) you WANT TO achieve, is this :

```css
html {
    text-align : right
}
```

```html
<span>28 Main Street - 00000 - CITY - COUNTRY</span>
</br>
<span>Main Street - 00000 - CITY - COUNTRY</span>
```

This positions your text at the right of the screen, but your letters still read from left to right!

Comment: Thanks for you answers, but I want the text to be read from right to left (when the website is in arabe for exemple) . What I do not understand is why when I change the reading direction the number somehow change goes to the other side

Comment: so you mean you want results like COUNTRY-CITY-00000-STREET-MAIN 28

Comment: Yes what at least would seem logical, or for it not to change, and what I do not understand is why when I do something like "28 something - something more", I endup with "something - something more 28", while if I try to reverse "p 28 something - something more", it does not change